# Execute MDX with WITH Clause in T-SQL throws errors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssas, mdx

Ref: [Grouping SSAS members into buckets using MDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537412/grouping-ssas-members-into-buckets-using-mdx/34543094#34543094)

Thanks for the help with the question regarding grouping SSAS members into buckets using MDX. It works perfectly when run standalone in SSAS or directly in SSMS.

However, I tried to wrap the same in a T-SQL procedure to insert the records into a table using the below, the execution fails with an error message:

```
declare @query nvarchar(4500)
set @query = 'insert into ssas_results
              select * from OPENQUERY(ssaslink,''
                                   select * from 
 (
 WITH 
 SET [RestOfWorld] AS 
   {
  [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United Kingdom]
 ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany]
   } 
 MEMBER [Customer].[Customer Geography].[All].[RestOfWorld] AS 
  Aggregate
 (
  {
    [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United Kingdom]
   ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany]
  }
 ) 
SET [CountriesMinusROW] AS 
[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].MEMBERS - [RestOfWorld] 
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
,NON EMPTY 
  [Product].[Category].[Category]
* 
  {
    [CountriesMinusROW]
   ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[All].[RestOfWorld]
  } ON 1
 FROM [Adventure Works] 
WHERE 
[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2007] )'') AS SSASREC'

exec (@query)

When I executed the stored procedure, I get the error message:

OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "ssaslink" returned message     "Subselects and subcubes cannot define new calculations using the WITH clause.".
```

Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
     An error occurred while preparing the query "

Is this approach not supported in SSAS? What is the best way I can insert the results of the query into the table using a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in `OPENQUERY` needs to be a valid `MDX` since that is going to be executed upon the defined SSAS server instance. Get rid of the `select * from (...) AS SSASREC` construct and just keep the `MDX` inside quotes.

**Edited based on OP's comment**

For including parameters, MDX has the special [StrToMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146022.aspx) and [StrToSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144782.aspx) functions. 
NOTE: While using `StrToMember` / `StrToSet` is not really required in this case(as whytheq correctly said), there is certain level of security these functions can provide. When the second parameter in these functions is "CONSTRAINED", it will filter out injection attacks. So a "plus" on the security aspect.

From BOL

> When the CONSTRAINED flag is used, the member name must be directly resolvable to a qualified or unqualified member name. This flag is used to reduce the risk of injection attacks via the specified string. If a string is provided that is not directly resolvable to a qualified or unqualified member name, the following error appears: "The restrictions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOMEMBER function were violated."

Try something like below.

```
declare @query nvarchar(4500)
declare @date VARCHAR(30)

set @date = '[Date].[Calendar Year].&[' + '2007' + ']'

set @query = 'select * from OPENQUERY(ssaslink,                                 
''WITH 
 SET [RestOfWorld] AS 
   {
  [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United Kingdom]
 ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany]
   } 
 MEMBER [Customer].[Customer Geography].[All].[RestOfWorld] AS 
  Aggregate
 (
  {
    [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United Kingdom]
   ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany]
  }
 ) 
SET [CountriesMinusROW] AS 
[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].MEMBERS - [RestOfWorld] 
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
,NON EMPTY 
  [Product].[Category].[Category]
* 
  {
    [CountriesMinusROW]
   ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[All].[RestOfWorld]
  } ON 1
 FROM [Adventure Works] 
WHERE 
StrToMember('''+CAST(@date AS VARCHAR(50))+''',CONSTRAINED)'''


insert into ssas_results
exec (@query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Really just repeating what sourav has already said - you can simplify to something like this:

No need to use `StrToMember` in this context, as you are passing the whole script as a string...

```
DECLARE @Year INTEGER = YEAR(GETDATE());
DECLARE @DtString VARCHAR(50)= '[Date].[Calendar Year].&[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Year) + ']';

INSERT INTO ssas_results
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    OPENQUERY
    (
    ssaslink,
    '   
     WITH 
     SET [RestOfWorld] AS 
         {
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United Kingdom]
     ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany]
         } 
     MEMBER [Customer].[Customer Geography].[All].[RestOfWorld] AS 
        Aggregate
     (
        {
            [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United Kingdom]
         ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany]
        }
     ) 
    SET [CountriesMinusROW] AS 
    [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].MEMBERS - [RestOfWorld] 
    SELECT 
    NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
    ,NON EMPTY 
        [Product].[Category].[Category]
    * 
        {
            [CountriesMinusROW]
         ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[All].[RestOfWorld]
        } ON 1
     FROM [Adventure Works] 
    WHERE '
        +
            @DtString
        +
        ';'     
    );
```

Comment: Thank you whytheq and SouravA for responding. I do have to wrap it in a T-SQL procedure since the dates and a few other fields are variable and insert into a table for some other calculations. I did try that initially though  - to keep the MDX directly inside the quotes and got the same error. Will give it a shot once again - maybe I didnt do right the first time.

Comment: Upped, point taken. I have little experience with `OPENQUERY`. Your suggestion is valid.